# Compile java file with a package using Oracle JDK in ubuntu

Tags: java

I have successfully compiled this file and saved.

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hey!"); 
    }
}
```

using

```
javac a.java
```

```
java A
```

but when I compile this file:

```
package B;

class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hey!"); 
    }
}
```

now, again using the same commands it do compile but never run

```
javac a.java
```

```
java A       
// could not find or load main class
```

Please guide me the exact command for the terminal to run the file.

**Note:** The file is named "a.java".

Comment: `java B.A` - you should specify package

Comment: might be helpful - [package and folder names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395916/package-name-is-different-than-the-folder-structure-but-still-java-code-compiles)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the fully-qualified name, i.e. `packageName.ClassName`:

```
java B.A
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the directory to the directory wich contains the path 'B' (your package name) and than call `java B.A`

Comment: ... and A.java must be saved in the path `./B/A.java`

Comment: No, `javac` doesn't require the package name. `java` does.

Comment: I went to the directory, A.class is in the same location with a.java, thus again I am having the same error @Axel

Comment: @RohanChauhan you mist be in the directory that contans directory B and inside B must be A.class.

Comment: @Jens I dont have any directory inside my "java" directory in which I saved the a.java file. even when I use "cd B" its says, directory does not exist.

Comment: @RohanChauhan If you have a package B, so you must have the class in the directory 'B'.

Comment: I just created a directory and named it B, and stored the class A.class in it. Now it workd. I guess jdk donot create directory itself. So now its working

Comment: @RohanChauhan No jdk will not creating any directory.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above, You need to specify the fully-qualified name, i.e. packageName.ClassName:

```
        >> javac a.java
        >> java B.A
```

But you need to create the directory named "packageName" yourself as jdk does not create one for you implicitly.

Comment: with `javac -d` it does - see [javac manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html)