How to Change the Package Name of an Android App?
So, I have a latest version of android studio and Im trying to rename the package but when I do with its making a new folder instead of renaming the package only. The application is made with java+kotlin
How can I fix that?
I want to change the package name only not to create a new folder and do the work again

You can't do that unfortunately.
The package name corresponds to the folder structure on the file system.
You can use the refactor from Android Studio to rename the package, but it will also change the folder structure.. Why is it that you don't want to change the folder structure?

correct, I just want to rename the package and dont want to change structure. It was working in old version but not in new

See this question and answer, and maybe rename the package name manually without using the IDE. But it is not the convention, git would know a file has been renamed if the path is changed so no issues with the SCM and modification hisroty:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395916/package-name-is-different-than-the-folder-structure-but-still-java-code-compiles

The app packageName (the one that ends in AndroidManifest.xml) has nothing to do with the package name the Java/Kotlin code sources are stored in. Which one do you want to change?

here is the video of what Im facing its making a new folder of notes instead of changing the actual name
video

To rename a package in your Android Studio without creating a new folder, follow these steps:

Open the Project in Android Studio
In the Project tool window, switch to the "Project" view instead of "Android" view.
Locate the Package: Expand the directories under src/main/java (or src/main/kotlin if applicable
Right-click on the package name you want to rename.
Select Refactor > Rename
-Android Studio will show you a preview of the changes that will be made. Review them to ensure that only the package name is being changed and not creating new folders
-Click "Do Refactor" to apply the changes
-Ensure that the applicationId in your build.gradle file reflects the new package name if it’s changed
-Sync and Rebuild
enter image description here


here is the video of what Im facing its making a new folder of notes instead of changing the actual name
video
